# Is there a way to induct the player-manager in the Hall of Fame?

Tags: fifa-manager-2013

So, I'm playing FIFA Manager 2013 and decided that I'll have a go at being both player and manager. After playing a set number of matches, a player can be inducted in the club's Hall of Fame. Doing so for other players is easy, just right-click on their names and then "Induct in Hall of Fame", except when right-clicking on the Player/Manager, you get sent directly to the player details page, and there are no buttons that suggest inducting yourself in your club's Hall of Fame.

Is there a way to induct the player/manager in the Hall of Fame?

Comment: No there isn't..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you simply can't do this.